# Value Representation Issue

Tags: c++

The input for a,b,c are 25,27.5,40.
The correct answer that should be displayed is 754573.2, but I continue getting 754573.17 despite reading about how to solve this. I also am not allowed to use setprecision() to solve the issue.
What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    double a, b, c;
    double g;
    double v;
    double ci = 123.00; 
    double i = 15;



    cout << "enter the 3 values: ";
    cin  >> a >> b >> c;

    a = a * i;
    b = b * i;
    c = c * i;
    v = a * b * c;
    g = static_cast<int>(v / ci * 100 + .5) / 100.0;

    cout << "The answer is " << g;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks everyone! I got it to work.

Comment: can you use ```printf("%.2f\n", g);```?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I have to use static_cast to solve the problem.

Comment: `cout << "The answer is " << setprecision(10) << g;`. The default precision is 6 - six significant digits are printed.

Comment: since you are not allowed setprecision, you could split the answer in two integers for integer and fractional parts, and output those separately.

Answer (score 2):

cout is using a default precision, and that is why the output is rounded to 5 digits.

To see that, call cout::precision();

A cheesy answer to try is using sprintf:

```
char *result = char[256];
sprintf(&result, "%.2lf", g);
cout << result;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int g = static_cast<int>(v / ci);
int h = static_cast<int>((100 * v / ci) + 0.5);
int i = h - g * 100;

cout << "The answer is " << g << "." << i << "\n";
```